# Angular async validator check unicity of input in database

Tags: angular, validation, asynchronous, angular-custom-validators

I have an `<input>` where the user enter a value that is supposed to be unique in database. I want to check dynamically in the front-end if that value is unique or not.

I want also to display an error message if the value is already stored in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom async validator to do that. Let's say you want to check that the name is unique. First, create a new file for the async validator :

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class NameValidator {

    constructor(private nameService: NameService) { }

    CheckNameValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<{ [key: string]: boolean } | null> => {
            return this.nameService.nameExists(control.value)
                .pipe(
                    map(valueExists => {
                        if (valueExists) {
                            return { nameExists: true };
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                    )
                )
        }
    }
```

The validator is a service where you import the service nameService where you can call your api. The api must return if the value is present or not. Then, in the controller :

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private nameValidator: NameValidator 
    ) {}

public formGroup: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void { 
  
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)], [this.nameValidator.CheckNameValidator()]]
    }, {updateOn: 'blur'});
  }
```

When you build your formgroup, each form control can hold a value, an array of validators, and an array of async validators. That's where i put the call to the asyn validator service.

Notice the `{updateOn: 'blur'}`, if you do not write this, the update to check the validators is on change, so you make way too many api calls. With onBlur the api call is done onblur => performance gain.

If you use angular material, your view should look something like this :

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <mat-form-field class="field-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
        <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls['name'].errors?.nameExists">This name is already in use</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```